# Join new columns based on row values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called **flux** with :

```
INSERT INTO `flux` (`id`, `name`) VALUES

(20, 'test1'),
(21, 'test2');
```

And a table called **flux_rules** with :

```
INSERT INTO `flux_rules` (`id`, `id_flux`, `id_modele_scrape`, `disallow`) VALUES

(1, 20, 1, 1),
(2, 21, 1, 1);
```

And one more table called **modele_scrape** with :

```
INSERT INTO `modele_scrape` (`id`, `modele`) VALUES

(1, 'renault captur'),
(2, 'renault zoe');
```

I believe this is a pretty usual setup, but what I haven't found information on what I'm trying to achieve, which is a SELECT query that would list all rows from **modele_scrape** with a column for each row in **flux** where the value is defined by the **flux_rules** column (1 IF EXISTS, ELSE 0) :

```
modele_scrape.id     modele_scrape.modele    test1    test2
1                    test                    1        0
```

Right now I have working query, but it only works to join one row from flux :

```
SELECT id AS id, 

(SELECT IF (EXISTS (SELECT id_flux, id_modele_scrape FROM flux_rules WHERE id_flux = 20 AND id_modele_scrape = modele_scrape.id), 1, 0) ) AS disallowed

FROM modele_scrape
```

The solution should work as to dynamically join X amount of columns where X is the amount of rows in **flux** (rows from this table can be added/deleted)

Comment: Sample data and expected result are needed. (you could setup a sqlfiddle perhaps?) I think you need ("conditional aggregates" and 'group by') or use of "pivot" from your description but without data its hard to know for sure

Comment: I haven't been able to make a SQLfiddle (building schema doesn't work) but I am adding the data right now.

Comment: good alternative for sqlfiddle is https://dbfiddle.uk but perhaps you could consider my answer before doing much more on the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generically this sounds like a desire to "pivot" your information, and this may achieved by using "conditional aggregates" (basically this means using a case expression inside an aggregate function, typically this is the `max()` function.

```
select
      m.id 
    , m.modele
    , max(case when r.r.flux_id = 1 then flux.name end) as `name1`
    , max(case when r.r.flux_id = 2 then flux.name end) as `name2`
    , max(case when r.r.flux_id = 3 then flux.name end) as `name3`
from modele_scrape as m
left join flux_rules as r on m.id = r.id_modele_scrape
left join flux as f on r.flux_id  = f.id
group by
      m.id 
    , m.modele
```

**Dynamic Pivot in MySQL**

To produce such a pivot dynamically, the following query will work:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      ' max(case when  r.id_flux = ''',
      id,
      ''' then 1 else 0 end) ',
      name
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  flux;
  
set @sql = CONCAT('SELECT m.id, m.modele,', @sql,  
' from modele_scrape as m',
' left join flux_rules as r on m.id = r.id_modele_scrape',
' left join flux as f on r.id_flux  = f.id',
' group by m.id, m.modele') 
;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

```
 id | modele         | test1 | test2
 -: | :------------- | ----: | ----:
  1 | renault captur |     1 |     1
  2 | renault zoe    |     0 |     0
```

see this as a [working model here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6189981e53ca68bd6d407df156cf001d&hide=22)

NOTE: due to limited sample data I chose to produce the dynamic columns by directly querying the `flux` table, in the real tables this might produce more columns than you want/need so adjust the group_concat query, perhaps with joins to other tables and/or a where clause, to suit your data and requirements

Comment: note: within the case expressions shown above I have oped to use flux.name as the value you would see in the result, this is just an arbitrary choice it could be some other column from the flux table but wasn't sure what column to use.

Comment: Thank you for your take on this. While this seems to work, it would join a fixed amount of columns (3) but I'm looking for a way to join a column for each row in flux, and rows can be added/deleted.

I updated my question to make this a bit clearer, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I have added dynamic sql to my answer. The only way to dynamically pivot is to use "dynamic sql" which is sql used to generate other sql. There are many examples of using dynamic sql for pivots available, and now there is another.

Comment: This is way more complex than I expected, thank you very much for your sharing your knowledge !